# Scilab Making GUI

Tags: scilab

How to use two functions in Scilab 5.5 GUI Building? For example, If I want to add and substract two numbers choosing a popupmenu option and execute it with a pushbutton option. Please reply, I am new in Scilab.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point I recommend to read tutorial about GUIs in Scilab.
[for example, this](http://www.openeering.com/sites/default/files/LHY_Tutorial_Gui.pdf)